# Is there a way to create a new file from the editior once I have a file open?

Tags: linux-ubuntu, python

So I have the following file `number11.py` open in vim, this is the route I usually take to create a new file I do `ESC` `:save number11.py`, and then `:x`. Then from my Ubuntu terminal I do the following `vim number12.py`. Is there a straight forward command I do from the beginning `ESC` to create the newfile `number12.py`?

Comment: You can use the command `:saveas {newfilename}`.  See `:help :saveas`

Comment: @Wolf Yeah that is what I was thinking because I have used that command before, however, I was researching and found that on StackOverflow they suggested using %.

Comment: `%` means the current file (and nice-to-know, `%:h` means the directory of the current file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is the following:

`ESC` `:w` to write (save) the file. Then `:e number12.py`. That will open a new buffer in the current window, if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks.